# GTM script breaking UI on IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-tag-manager

I have implemented `GTM` on our website and it's working fine on `Chrome` but on `IE` the same scripts creating issue it actually breaking the UI and when I remove the `GTM scripts` UI works fine on IE as well.

Is there any prerequisites for `IE`. Any pointer or suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give us more information - code snippets, details of the tags that are running, etc.

Comment: Please read this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/xS_EMBG5I5M. This problem can be associated with "Do not track" option in IE

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue can be associated with "Do not track" option in IE

please go through [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Enable-or-Disable-Do-Not-Track-in-Internet-Explorer-10-307811.shtml) to resolve.